# Multiple list nesting with split(), R

Tags: r, list, nested, lapply, mapply

Given a dataset with multiple unique elements in a column, I'd like to split those unique elements into new dataframes, but have the dataframe nested one level down.  Essentially adding an extra level to the `split()` command.

For instance (using the built-in `iris` table as an example:

```
iris
mylist <- split(iris, iris$Species)
```

produces a list, `mylist`, that contains 3 sublists, `setosa`, `versicolor`, `virginica`.

```
mylist[["setosa"]]

       Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

But I would actually like to nest that data table in a sublist called `results` BUT keep the upper level list name as `setosa`. Such that:

```
mylist$setosa["results"]

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

I could do this with manual manipulation, but I'd like this to run automatically.  I've tried unsuccessfully with `mapply`

```
mapply(function(names, df) 
   names <- split(df, df[["Species"]]), 
   unique(iris$Species), iris)
```

Any advice? Also happy to use a `tidyr` package if that makes things easier...

Comment: `dplyr::group_by(iris, Species) %>% tidyr::nest() %>% %>% { set_names(.$data, .$Species) }` ; `split(iris, iris$Species) %>% as.list()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider `by` (object-oriented wrapper to `tapply`), very similar to `split` but allows you to run a function on each subset. Often many useRs run `split` + `lapply`, unaware both can replaced with `by`:

```
mylist <- by(iris, iris$Species, function(sub) list(results=sub), simplify = FALSE)

head(mylist$setosa$results)
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa

head(mylist$versicolor$results)
#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
# 51          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
# 52          6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
# 53          6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
# 54          5.5         2.3          4.0         1.3 versicolor
# 55          6.5         2.8          4.6         1.5 versicolor
# 56          5.7         2.8          4.5         1.3 versicolor

head(mylist$virginica$results)
#     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
# 101          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5 virginica
# 102          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica
# 103          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1 virginica
# 104          6.3         2.9          5.6         1.8 virginica
# 105          6.5         3.0          5.8         2.2 virginica
# 106          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1 virginica
```

Comment: This is perfect. Wasn't even aware of "by". Thanks!!

Comment: Great to hear! Indeed `by` I have found is an underutilized method.

Answer (score 3):

`setNames` in `lapply` will keep the names of the list you're iterating through

```
iris
mylist <- split(iris, iris$Species)
mylist2 <- lapply(setNames(names(mylist), names(mylist)), function(x){
  list(results = mylist[[x]])
})
```

Comment: Works, but going with the simpler 'by' solution above. Thanks!